# How to change color related to progress of progress bar in Android

Tags: android, colors, progress

How to change color related to progress of progress bar?
I want to make to the end of progress bar more intense red color.
For example from blue to red.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/storage_progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="10"
        android:indeterminate="false"

thread {
   while (i < state) {
        i += 1
        Thread.sleep(100)
   }
   handler.post {
        storage_progress_bar.progress = i
   }
```

Comment: Please start showing how you color a progress bar.